# Performance data collection and visualisation tool

Tags: performance, testing, automation, visualization

I have a performance test suite that during the run collects response time information (in a CSV format). Also I have a set of monitoring scripts that collect running application metrics (also in CSV format) on the server. I would like to automate a visualisation of those datasets (basically, time series) e.g. some web application where I can upload all datasets and get them displayed in a nice chart with posbility of filtering by time period, displaying data in different slices and correlating with other datasets based on time. Do you guys know of something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particularly popular tool for just this purpose is [rrdtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/).

If you are interested in the most sophisticated analytical tools available for time series, I'd recommend [R](http://www.r-project.org/), and for a web interface, either [RApache](http://rapache.net/) or [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) in server mode.  I suspect that that would be overkill, if you're primarily interested in a dashboard-style tool.

Comment: thanks a lot for your links. RApache looks very intresting. do you know what are the limits of that? i.e. how much data it can handle? can it support custom time slot selection?

Comment: A clear answer is hard to give, but I'll try.  RApache is simply an Apache front-end for R, all of the visualization would be generated by R. So the question would really be about what R can support.  Using memory mapped files, one can easily scale R to terabytes on up - whatever your HDs support...  However, the variety and # of tricks and whatnot that I use for very large data sets are rather advanced among most users, so I wouldn't really encourage you to pick it up and start doing anything beyond MBs or possibly GBs of data per day.

Comment: (Continued) The upper limit of what's feasible in R is pretty much the same as with any other system.  For many purposes, the easy stuff is probably easier in R and the hard stuff is not necessarily harder or easier, but gets you into a more, well, esoteric population.  :)

Comment: (Continued) Basically, as much as I like R, I would recommend starting with `rrdtool` or a similar such system, and then consider what you may migrate to later, if your needs change.

Comment: Thanks! My use case is really about building a dashboard that can show monitoring data (CPU, number of database connections etc.) grouped by  performance run and each performance run will probably not last for more than a day.

Comment: That sounds like it's quite fine for `rrdtool`, plus you get nice plugins to other systems and can compare it to existing usage for other monitoring programs.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be a tool called [KNIME](http://knime.org/), an open-source data integration, processing, analysis, and exploration platform. It has a bunch of time series nodes for processing and analyzing data in a time series, as well as nodes for reading and writing to different data stores.

Probably overkill for your problem, but may be useful for someone else who needs to analyze data in a time series.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, that KNIME also has integrated Java, Python and R scripting nodes, so if you can't find a way to do something with one of its native nodes, you can roll your own script to get the job done.