# StatsD type server for advanced analytics

Tags: real-time, analytics, analysis

My company is growing and so is our need for analytics.

But concurrently we are needing greater speed and complexity.

I'm looking for recommendations to FOSS stats servers similar to StatsD, but capable of more complexity. On the scale of things like [cohort charts](http://blog.mixpanel.com/2009/02/08/using-analytics-to-understand-visitor-retention/), grouping actions by category and extracting unique vs total.

Comment: Why not Google Analytics?  See also [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167593/performance-data-collection-and-visualisation-tool/7167706)

Comment: because GA doesn't do cohort charts.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? In a similar situation myself...